# Compilation errors using miktex 2.9 and texstudio 2.12.18

Tags: texstudio, compilation-error, miktex2.9

During compilation, I am encountering strange errors. I believe the error is due to version mismatch of `pdftexcmds.sty` which is of version **2019/11/24 v0.31** on my PC as a part of Miktex distribution.

Here is an example using beamer (compiled using `pdflatex`)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{graphicx,float,subcaption}

\title[My Title]{Some Very Long Presentation Title}

\author[J. Doe]{John Doe}

\institute[XYZ] % (optional, but mostly needed)
{
    XYZ Institute of Technology

}

\date{}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{%
        \pgfsetfillopacity{100}\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\pgfsetfillopacity{1}\insertshortauthor~~(\insertshortinstitute)
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \pgfsetfillopacity{100}\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\pgfsetfillopacity{1}\insertshorttitle
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \pgfsetfillopacity{100}\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
            %\usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\pgfsetfillopacity{1}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
            \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex}
    \end{beamercolorbox}}%
    \vskip0pt%
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{First Slide}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item First item
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}


\end{document}
```

line 189: Undefined control sequence. \ifluatex

line 190: Extra \else. \else

line 271: Extra \fi. \fi

line 272: Undefined control sequence. \ifluatex

line 273: Undefined control sequence. \ifnum\luatexversion

line 273: Missing number, treated as zero. \ifnum\luatexversion<

line 281: Undefined control sequence. \pdftexcmds@directlua

line 281: Missing \begin{document}. \pdftexcmds@directlua

line 291: Extra \fi. \fi

line 316: Undefined control sequence. \ifluatex

line 316: Extra \else. \ifluatex\else

line 340: Extra \fi. \fi

line 421: Undefined control sequence. \ifluatex

line 425: Extra \else. \else

line 427: Extra \fi. \fi

line 485: Undefined control sequence. \ifluatex

line 486: Extra \else. \else

line 488: Extra \fi. \fi

line 158: Undefined control sequence. \onecolumn

line 158: Undefined control sequence. \onecolumn

**You have requested, on input line 186, version 2019/11/07 of package iftex, but only version 2013/04/04 v0.2 Provides if(tex) conditional for PDFTeX, XeTeX, and LuaTeX' is available.**

line 30: Overfull \hbox (22.475pt too wide) in paragraph

line 30: Overfull \hbox (6.38751pt too wide) in paragraph

line 30: Overfull \hbox (95.9039pt too wide) in paragraph

line 30: Overfull \hbox (230.98454pt too wide) in paragraph

line 30: Overfull \hbox (13.07918pt too wide) in paragraph

line 30: Overfull \hbox (26.18878pt too wide) in paragraph

line 30: Overfull \hbox (6.69167pt too wide) in paragraph

line 30: Overfull \hbox (23.72504pt too wide) in paragraph

line 30: Overfull \hbox (22.50836pt too wide) in paragraph

line 30: Overfull \hbox (27.10129pt too wide) in paragraph

line 30: Overfull \hbox (216.08034pt too wide) in paragraph

line 30: Overfull \hbox (15.81668pt too wide) in paragraph

line 30: Overfull \hbox (103.87305pt too wide) in paragraph

: name{Navigation1} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one

Here is the result.

[image]

[image]

[image]

However, if I compile using lualatex, correct pdf is generated (without the faulty first page) but these errors do not go away. Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Comment: update your miktex system. You have outdated files. Run the update manager in the console in user *and* admin mode.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Earlier I have updated only selected packages, but updating the complete miktex worked.